# Velocity.js | width animation start from 0px and not from element current value

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity

I want that the animation start from the element current width and height value, if the current element have width:225px and height:225px I want to start the animation from that value and decrease this value to 45px

And why if we replace velocity() function with animate() the animation is how I would like

**JS :**

```
$("#play-velocity").on('click', function(){
 $("#with-velocity").velocity({
    width: "45px",
    height: "45px"

  }, {
    duration: 2000
  });
});
```

**CSS :**

```
#with-velocity {
  display:block;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  background-color:red;
  width:225px;
  height:225px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/juu9gfca/18/)**

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still needing to fix this.

I think I found the WHY to your problem, unfortunately I wasn't able to fix it without some concessions. Apparently the syntax

```
$("#with-velocity").velocity({
    width: "45px",
    height: "45px"
}
```

is not supported or changed in the version of **Velocity.js** you are using in the fiddle - **2.0.2**, the next most current I could find with which you can use such syntax is the **1.5.1**.

I was not able to find the 2.0.2 equivalent to make the width change as expected, I hope this helps you in your search.

```js
$("#play-velocity").on('click', function(){
  $("#with-velocity").velocity({
    width: "45px",
    height: "45px"

  }, {
    duration: 3350
  });
});
```

```css
#with-velocity {

  display:block;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  background-color:red;
width:225px;
height:225px;
}

#with-velocit {
  color: #AAB2BD;
  font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width:50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#play-velocity {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:.5em;
  padding:10px;
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.1/velocity.min.js"></script>
<div id="with-velocity">   
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="play-velocity"><span class="ion ion-play"></span> Play</a>
```